Amplify Rewrites and redirects - Block direct access to file types
I have uploaded a Vue single page app to amplify via Bitbucket CICD. It is a simple static client-side SPA. Everything works so far so good.
Here is the default Rewrites and redirects setup that is in place. By the look of it, it is already restricting the JPG, PNG file types.
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>   


However, if I try to copy my webiste image URL from the debugger and access that URL directly in the address bar, I notice that the JPG/PNG pictures are still directly visible to me. As if the regular expression above in "Rewrites and redirects" is doing nothing?
I expect this "Rewrites and redirects" configuration to enable only showing JPG/PNG pictures to users on the website. If anyone wants to access the files directly, the user should be redirected back to /index.html
Is my understanding correct? What am I doing wrong?

That's the expected behavior. I believe the expression is the opposite of how you're interpreting it.
If you hit any url that is NOT filename-dot-extention (where "extension" is one of the excluded extensions in the list) the url is rewritten to be index.html.
Any hit to a '.html' file will be rewritten and routed within your app.
Files with the excluded extensions are generally static assets. If you directly access your .css, .png, .jpg files, they will be returned directly (no rewrite).
